# Deleting each notification as a user accepts

Tags: facebook-graph-api, notifications, facebook-php-sdk

How can I make the app delete the notifications as a user accepts them? For example the user sends a request to friends, the users are then notified of this before giving the option to accept or reject.  On acceptance I need to enter some info into a database, which isn't the problem I'm having.

I'm using the code below, and the problem i'm finding is when the user has multiple requests from different people.  It's either deleting all of the requests or none at all, ideally I need it to delete each request the user has accepted. Any ideas?

```
$request = $facebook->api("/me/apprequests");

foreach ($request as $data) {       
    echo "<form method='post'>";   
        foreach ($data as $full_request_id) {
            echo "<input type='submit' name='yes' id='yes' value='Yes'>";
                if ((isset($_POST['yes']))) {
                    try {
                        $delete_success = $facebook->api("/$full_request_id",'DELETE');
                        if ($delete_success) {
                            echo "Successfully deleted " . $full_request_id;}
                        else {
                           echo "Delete failed".$full_request_id;}
                        }          
                        catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
                echo $e;}
                }
                echo "</form>";
        }           
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's sample code on the page for the Requests dialog: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/requests/

I believe the recommended workflow is to delete all pending requests for that user (from Facebook's side); if you still need the user to manually accept them one by one after they click the first one, you can render your own interface for the remaining requests

This is what apps like Cityville do - when you click through from a Facebook requests they clear all your Facebook requests and render their own dialog for you to accept the remaining (now hidden from Facebook's onterface) gifts.